# Selenium Python how to find //span number between two values

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

HTML Sample:

```html
<div class="lend-count">
<span>50</span>
</div>
<div class="lend-count">
<span>55</span>
</div>
<div class="lend-count">
<span>25</span>
</div>
<div class="lend-count">
<span>45</span>
</div>
<div class="lend-count">
<span>25</span>
</div>
<div class="lend-count">
<span>30</span>
</div>
<div class="lend-count">
<span>25</span>
</div>
<div class="lend-count">
<span>15</span>
</div>
<div class="lend-count">
<span>10</span>
</div>
```

In selenium chrome webdriver. I am trying to find the first span that is between range of numbers (10-20), in this case **15**, then click it. If nothing on this page(throw NoSuchElementException), click the next page button and loop back try again:

```
        while True:
            try:
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[number(.)= <10, >20]").click()
                time.sleep (1)
                break
            except NoSuchElementException:
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='anticon anticon-right']").click()                     
                time.sleep (1)
```

Tried to use range as well:

```
price = range (10,20) 
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[number(.)= 'price']").click()
```

Please advise

Comment: Please share the page URL or HTML or at least the HTML of that specific element

Comment: I just added the HTML sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='lend-count']/span[number()>10 and number()<20]").click()
```

Simply use number()>10 and number()<20 to get numbers between a range. To make sure it's appearing use webdriver waits.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='lend-count']/span[number()>10 and number()<20]"))).click()
```

Will check for 10 seconds if a span with those values comes up and will then throw an exception.

```
while True:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='lend-count']/span[number()>10 and number()<20]"))).click()
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@class='anticon anticon-right']"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: does the website needs to be refreshed (driver.refresh()) periodically,  in order for the code to find the elements? shouldn't I use visibility or presence instead of clickable?

Comment: This waits for the element to popup for 10 seconds and then does the nosuchelement exception. Refreshing the page would just reload all the elements defeating the point unless the elements somehow differ after each reload.

Answer (score 1):

You can store all web element with XPath `//span[text()]` in a list like below, and then iterate using a loop and put a condition `if int(span_text.text) < 10 and int(span_text.text) >20`.

**Code:**

```
while True:
    try:
        list_of_span_tag_text = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text()]")
        for span_text in list_of_span_tag_text:
            if int(span_text.text) < 10 and int(span_text.text) >20:
                span_text.click()
                time.sleep(1)
                break
            else:
                print("None of the span on this page satisfy this condtion, span_text.text <10 and span_text.text > 20")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='anticon anticon-right']").click()
        time.sleep(1)
```

**Update 1:**

```
while True:
    try:
        list_of_span_tag_text = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text() < 20][text() > 10]")
        for span_text in list_of_span_tag_text:
            span_text.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            break
        else:
            print("None of the span on this page satisfy this condtion, span_text.text < and span_text.text > 20")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='anticon anticon-right']").click()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I got the follow error with the code:                                                                              Exception has occurred: ValueError
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0xb36a...d940'

Comment: got the following error: Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: I actually had the loop broken...the loop continues even when found span...

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
while 1:

```
   len_click = 0 #remains 0 if no spans are in range 10-20
       try:
           #contains all the span with number in range.
           lst = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[number()>10][number()<20]") 
           len_click = len(lst)
           if(click!=0): #shows no span exist in range 10 to  20.
               lst[0].click
           else:
               #code for next page.
       except NoSuchElementException:
           #code for next page.
```

Please comment below if you face any issue.

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer. I just added more lines to my initial code. not sure how to apply here.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestion. I'll add comments.